# Mental Maths game

Tags: python, python-3.x, quiz

I have made a mental Maths game but it seems quite long, is there anyway in which I can simplify it? And can you also help me with my other Maths game, [Ten quick questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113730/ten-questions-maths-game) ?

```
correctq=0
actualanswer = 0
print("Welcome to Mental Maths")
print("If you chose Division rpund down to the nearest whole number")
mode = input("(A)ddition, (S)ubtraction, (M)ultiplication or (D)ivision?")
hardness = input("(E)asy, (M)edium or (H)ard?")
questions=int(input("Enter the amount of questions:"))
if mode == "A":
    if hardness == "E":
        from random import randint
        for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(1,100)
            number2 = randint(1,100)
            questionno = i + 1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno) +": " + str(number1) + " + "+ str(number2) + " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 + number2
            if answer == actualanswer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)

    elif hardness == "M":
        from random import randint
        for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(100,1000)
            number2 = randint(100,1000)
            questionno = i + 1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno) + ": " + str(number1)+ " + " + str(number2) + " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 + number2
            if answer == actualanswer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)

    elif hardness == "H":
        from random import randint
        for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(1000,10000)
            number2 = randint(1000,10000)
            questionno = i + 1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno)+": "+str(number1) + " + " + str(number2) + " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 + number2
            if answer == actualanswer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)

    else:
        print("Please enter the letter E, M or H, nothing else")

elif mode == "S":
   if hardness == "E":
        from random import randint
        for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(50,100)
            number2 = randint(1,50)
            questionno=i+1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno)+": "+str(number1)+ " - "+ str(number2) + " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 - number2
            if answer == actualanswer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)


   elif hardness == "M":
        from random import randint
        for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(500,1000)
            number2 = randint(100,500)
            questionno=i+1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno)+": "+str(number1)+ " - "+ str(number2) + " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 - number2
            if answer == actualanswer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)

   elif hardness == "H":
        from random import randint
        for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(5000,10000)
            number2 = randint(1000,5000)
            questionno=i+1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno)+": "+str(number1)+ " - "+ str(number2) + " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 - number2
            if answer == actualanswer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)

   else:
    print("Please enter the letter E, M or H, nothing else")


elif mode == "M":
   if hardness == "E":
        from random import randint
        for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(1,10)
            number2 = randint(1,5)
            questionno=i+1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno)+": "+str(number1)+ " x "+ str(number2) + " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 * number2
            if answer == actualanswer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)

   elif hardness == "H":
        from random import randint
        for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(50,100)
            number2 = randint(1,50)
            questionno=i+1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno)+": "+str(number1)+ " x "+ str(number2)+ " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 * number2
            if answer == actualanswer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)
   elif hardness == "M":
        from random import randint
        for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(5,20)
            number2 = randint(1,15)
            questionno=i+1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno)+": "+str(number1) + " x " + str(number2) + " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 * number2
            if actualanswer == answer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was "+actualanswer)




   else:
      print("Please enter the letter E, M or H, nothing else")

elif mode == "D":
   if hardness == "E":
      from random import randint
      for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(10,100)
            number2 = randint(1,10)
            questionno=i+1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno)+": "+str(number1)+ " Ã· "+ str(number2) + " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 / number2
            actualanswer=int(actualanswer)
            if answer == actualanswer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)

   elif hardness == "M":
        from random import randint
        for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(50,200)
            number2 = randint(10,50)
            questionno=i+1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno)+": "+str(number1)+ " Ã· "+ str(number2) + " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 / number2
            actualanswer=int(actualanswer)
            if answer == actualanswer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)

   elif hardness == "H":
        from random import randint
        for i in range(questions):
            number1 = randint(100,500)
            number2 = randint(50,100)
            questionno=i+1
            answer = int(input(str(questionno)+": "+str(number1)+ " Ã· "+ str(number2) + " = "))
            actualanswer = number1 / number2
            actualanswer=int(actualanswer)
            if answer == actualanswer:
                print("Correct!")
                correctq = correctq + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)

   else:
       print("Please enter the letter E, M or H, nothing else")

else:
    print("Please enter the lettr A, S, M or D, nothing else")
print("You got " + str(correctq) + " qustions right out of " + str(questions))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You repeat this section all over the place:

> ```
> from random import randint
> for i in range(questions):
>     number1 = randint(1,100)
>     number2 = randint(1,100)
>     questionno = i + 1
>     answer = int(input(str(questionno) +": " + str(number1) + " + "+ str(number2) + " = "))
>     actualanswer = number1 + number2
>     if answer == actualanswer:
>         print("Correct!")
>         correctq = correctq + 1
>     else:
>         print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)
> ```

You should move that into a method of its own, and just call it with the parameters:

```
def playAddition(min, max)
    from random import randint
    for i in range(questions):
        number1 = randint(min, max)
        number2 = randint(min, max)
        questionno = i + 1
        answer = int(input(str(questionno) +": " + str(number1) + " + "+ str(number2) + " = "))
        actualanswer = number1 + number2
        if answer == actualanswer:
            print("Correct!")
            correctq = correctq + 1
        else:
            print("Wrong, the answer was ", actualanswer)
```

Now you can call `playGame(1, 100)` and `playGame(100, 1000)`, etc., instead of all that duplication.  You will find heavy duplication between your `addition()`, `subtraction()`, etc. functions that can be removed too.  I leave this as an exercise for the reader.

---

Your naming is a mite hard to read, with `longnameswithoutanyobviouswordboundaries`.  You should look into the [PEP8 naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

---

Last, but not least, you should put your starting code in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` function.  This will [prevent problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) when you start working with code in multiple files.

Comment: Thanks, thought about using a defy but didn't know how with different numbers, will try fixing it now

Answer (score 4):

#### PEP8

Please do read the entire [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). From top to bottom. It's not that long and extremely useful, and should be the baseline when programming in Python. [@Hosch250](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/34073/hosch250) pointed out about the naming, but this style guide has a lot more advices that apply to your code, to name just a few:

- import statements should be at the beginning of the file
- spacing around operators

#### Magic strings

The strings "E", "M", "H" appear multiple times. When you use the exact same literal in multiple places, put it in a variable or constant, at the top of the file, for example:

```
LEVEL_HIGH = "H"
LEVEL_MEDIUM = "M"
LEVEL_LOW = "L"
```

#### Augmented assignment

Instead of this:

> ```
> correctq = correctq + 1
> ```

You can simplify to this shorter form:

```
correctq += 1
```

#### Formatting strings

Instead of string concatenation like this:

> ```
> print("You got " + str(correctq) + " qustions right out of " + str(questions))
> ```

Formatted expressions are often easier to read:

```
print("You got {} qustions right out of {}".format(correctq, questions))
```

Btw there are quite a lot of typos in the texts printed by the code.

As another example, instead of this:

> ```
> answer = int(input(str(questionno)+": "+str(number1) + " x " + str(number2) + " = "))
> ```

Consider this:

```
prompt = "{}: {} x {} = ".format(questionno, number1, number2)
answer = int(input(prompt))
```

How much easier is that to read?

Comment: Thanks you @Janos, I will take this forward in my future programs

Comment: I will read the PEP8 now